# select images as per choice and display their name as an alert in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, selection

I am new here, I have generated 5 images from an array. Now I want to select those images as we select using checkbox (means i can select 1 image or 2 image or more as per choice). After selecting I want to display their name as an alert that you have selected these images. Please guide me because i am new in javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "their name"? Do you mean the name attribute or just text below/above the images? Also, please show relevant code so we can help you easier :).

Comment: actually I have ten numbers from 1-10. I want to show images instead of numbers. e.g for 1 number I want to use '1.jpg' image.When user select that image alert shown as that you have choosed number 1. when user select '1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg' it will alert that you have choosed 1,2 and 3 number.

Comment: The fiddle works, it is easy to adapt to that number scenario. You can accept the answer and do your thing now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what an acceptable output is but here is something which accumulates selected photos and displays the image src for the selected photos.

```
var PhotoSrcArray = [
   "http://placekitten.com/g/60/60",
   "http://placekitten.com/70/60",
   "http://placekitten.com/g/60/70",
   "http://placekitten.com/70/70",
   "http://placekitten.com/g/80/80"
];

for(var i = 0; i < PhotoSrcArray.length; i++){
    $("#imgs").append('<li><label><input type="checkbox"></input><img src="'+PhotoSrcArray[i] + '" data-index="'+(i+1).toString() + '"/></label></li>');
}

var myArray = [];

$("li input").change(function(event){
    if (this.checked){
       myArray.push($(event.currentTarget).next('img').attr('data-index')); 
    }
    else {
       var indexOfPhoto = myArray.indexOf($(event.currentTarget).next('img').attr('data-index'));
       if (indexOfPhoto > -1){
            myArray.splice(indexOfPhoto, 1);
       }
    }
    myArray.sort();
    $("#output").html( myArray.join(' '));
    //or alert it if you'ld like
});
```

Here is a [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyNovo/LsU7T/).

Answer (score 0):

This is the working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WX8ud/).

You can try this function, it will *bind* a checkbox to an image:

```
function bind_checkbox_image(checkboxId, imageId)
{
    document.getElementById(checkboxId).onchange = function () {

        alert(document.getElementById(imageId).getAttribute("title"));
    };
}
```

The image should have a title and a change on the checkbox will show that title:

```
<img id="myimage" title="the image text" src="..." />
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" />
```

You can now bind those:

```
bind_checkbox_image("mycheckbox", "myimage");
```

EDIT: bugfix inverted ids of checkbox and image